# Need to change fsocketopen to CURL to be able to navigate redirects

Tags: php, curl

I have a php script that I recently added an array to. The php script checks URL's from the array for a set of text also in the array. Everything works great except the script will not follow redirects or check sub-pages.
I have been told that this is a limitation of fsocketopen and that I need to use CURL.
If this is the case then I require some assistance converting this from using fsocketopen to CURL. Hopefully there is some way to get fsocketopen to follow redirects or at least access sub-pages.

```
function check($host, $find){
    $fp = fsockopen($host, 80, $errno, $errstr, 10);
    if (!$fp){
        echo "$errstr ($errno)\n";
    } else {
        $header = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n";
        $header .= "Host: $host\r\n";
        $header .= "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";
        fputs($fp, $header);
        while (!feof($fp)) {
            $str.= fgets($fp, 1024);
        }
        fclose($fp);
        return (strpos($str, $find) !== false);
    }
}

function alert($host){
    $headers = 'From: Set your from address here';
    mail('my-email@my-domain.com', 'Website Monitoring', $host.' is down' $headers);
}

$hostMap = array(
    'www.my-domain.com' => 'content on site',
    'www.my-domain2.com' => 'content on second site',
);

//if (!check($host, $find)) alert($host);
foreach ($hostMap as $host => $find){
    if( !check( $host, $find ) ){
        alert($host);
    }
}
unset($host);
unset($find);
```

Apparently I wasn't clear in my question. I am looking for confirmation that fsocketopen cannot follow redirects or that it cannot go to a sub-page (url.com/subpage).
If this is the case, is CURL my best option and are there any examples I can look at?

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a "please code this for me" website. If you need help with something specific or don't know why something does/doesn't work, that's fine. Try it yourself. Check the documentation. Look for other examples if you can't figure it out.

Comment: Well how about confirming or not that my assumptions are correct regarding fsocketopen. I don't recall asking for someone to code this for me. I asked for assistance, that includes pointing someone in the right direction.

Comment: `fsockopen` on its own won't follow redirects, however if you see http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php#52033 you might get an idea how this can be accomplished if you made some sort of recursive function. Just make sure you put some sort of limit on the number of redirects in the case of redirection loops, which is what most browsers do.

Comment: Thanks for the link Mike, some good examples there.

Answer (score 0):

When you get the data returned from `feof()`, you can parse out the redirect information from the headers and create connect to that, but that is kind of annoying and `cURL` does it on its own.

You should just be able to use

```
$ch = curl_init($host);
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
   CURLOPT_RETUNTRANSFER => true
   , CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true
   , CURLOPT_HEADER => true
));
$str = curl_exec($ch);
```

`cURL` follows redirects by default using the `Location:` header.